# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attributes'

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting this error when i run redisco/models to connect to redis server using python, i can see this error is happening when 
from attributes import * is used, please let me know if any dependencies is missing for this from attributes module to run ?

Thanks,
Shailesh Nair.

Comment: Can you show us the code that produces the error?

Comment: This is the code which produces this error in pyhton : from redisco import models